# Echoing text and executing a command with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a command that spews json to stdout like so:

> foo inf --db

```
{
    "Name": "A rose by any any other",
    "Config": {
        "DBHost": "abc.efg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
        "DBName": "bsghshsgh",
        "DBUser": "bshshs",
        "DBPassword": "secret"
    }
}
```

I'd like to echo the contents of DBPasswod to the screen and then execute a pgsql command with the other paramaters like so. So far I can concatenate a string to send to stdout like so:

> foo inf --db | jq '"password: " + .Config.DBPassword  + ";  psql -h " + .Config.DBHost + " -U " + .Config.DBUser + " " + .Config.DBName'

How do I just echo the password to stdout and execute the pgsql command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is malformed.  Also, you should probably reconsider the sanity of this approach.  But if you insist to do it this way, you might try something like this:

```
foo inf --db | \
    jq -r '.Config | .DBPassword, .DBHost, .DBUser, .DBName' | \
    {
        read -r PGPASSWORD
        read -r host
        read -r user
        read -r db

        psql -h "$host" -U "$user" "$db"                
    }
```

(cf. [libpq-envars](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) for `PGPASSWORD`).

Comment: Well Ubuntu isn't respecting $PGPASSWORD, or any of the other variable, but otherwise this basically works.